# Return month names from current month

Tags: c#, arrays, date

I need help in C# getting month names from current month, meaning user inputs a month(name) and will return the list of months from the starting month until the current month.

Example; user inputs "August" and current month is "December" so it should return "August, September, October, November, December".

I've done a few steps but still can't get to it.

1st try:

```cs
string pattern = ("MMMM/yyyy"); 
            
Console.WriteLine("Enter Month: MMMM/yyyy");
DateTime inpMonth = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(),pattern,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
string last = inpMonth.ToString("MMMM/yyyy");

DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string curr = date.ToString("MMMM/yyyy");
```

2nd Try(new step):

```cs
//First Date
DateTime 1Date = new DateTime(2020, 12, 01);
 
//Second Date
DateTime 2Date =new  DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
 
int month1 = (2Date.Month - 1Date.Month);
int month2 = (2Date.Year - 1Date.Year) * 12; 
int months = month1 + month2;

string mon = months.DateTime.ToString("MMMM"); //trying to convert the month number to month name
```

Both try seems to not get any close result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will output to the result you requested:

```
var start = "August";
var today = DateTime.Today;
var date = new DateTime(today.Year, DateTime.ParseExact(start, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month, 1);
while (date < today)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{date:MMMM}");
   date = date.AddMonths(1);
}
```